# Как сказать по русски singable? Или singability?

Tags: переводы

Пишу работу на русском языке о переводе песен. Вопрос к тем, кто знают английский язык. Я не могу найти эквивалента ни в каком словаре. Помогите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

//------- это отставить, сослепу не то подумал.
Контекст бы... Если это бренд, то лучше не переводить.  
А если нет, то без контекста можно только догадываться. 
Все что угодно, вплоть до дееспособности (права подписи). 
//---------

А касательно песен, так это понятно. 
Это песенный; песенность, певучесть, напевность.
Способность быть пропетым, быть или стать песней.

Точного перевода, конечно, нет. Ориентируйтесь по смыслу.

Comment: Тут ведь не _sign_, а _sing_. О песнях, а не о подписях.

Comment: тьфу, спасибо. 
Совсем слепой стал...
То-то я думаю, слово какое-то "не такое".

Comment: "Это песенный; песенность, певучесть, напевность" - это **бред** (delirium), потому как эти слова *уже* имеют в русском языке *значение, никак не соотвествующее* смыслу перевода английского термина

Answer (score 1):

Если не в одно слово, то 'singable' — это *такой, который возможно пропеть*. А одним словом из существующих русских, по-моему, сказать невозможно, а можно только по аналогии с разговорным словом *"читабельный"* придумать новое слово *"певабельный".* :)

Comment: "читабельный" и подобное - это тоже не совсем по-русски. А вообще контекст нужен. В разных контекстах это может переводится по-разному и даже одним словом.

Comment: Одно дело фразу перевести с этим словом, а другое — само слово. В данном случае был вопрос о самих словах.